# Windows Command Line Script to rename a folder to current month -3 (e.g. 2009-04 to 2009-01)

Tags: windows, command-line, scripting

What would the Windows command line script be to rename a folder from the current month, to the current month - 3, using the format YYYY-MM ?

e.g.:

```
c:\myfiles\myFolder\
```

should become:

```
c:\myfiles\2009-01\
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For my locale, I need something different.

Also you need to deal with single-digit months, I suppose.

```
setlocal
@REM example:  Thu 06-11-2009
set stamp=%DATE%

@REM get the year
set year=%stamp:~10,4%
@REM example: 2009

@REM get the month
set month=%stamp:~4,2%
@REM example:  06

@REM subtract 3 months
set /a month=%month%-3
@REM example:  3

@REM test if negative (we rolled back beyond January 1st)
if %month% LSS 1  (
  set /a month=%month%+12
  @REM example: 8
  set /a year=%year%-1
  @REM example: 2008
)

@REM prepend with zero for single-digit month numbers
set month=0%month%

@REM take last 2 digits of THAT
set month=%month:~-2%

set newFolder=%year%-%month%

@REM move %1 %newFolder%
endlocal
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

I just had to tweak it for the UK date format (I should have mentioned that in the question). I'll post the UK version of your answer too. Plus I had to define %1 as the source folder.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to dissect the contents of `%DATE%` by yourself, unfortunately. There are no localization-safe date/time manipulation facilities in cmd.

For my locale (which uses standard ISO 8601 date format) I could just use the following:

```
@echo off
rem %DATE% comes back in ISO 8601 format here, that is, YYYY-MM-DD
set Y=%DATE:~0,4%
set /a M=%DATE:~5,2% - 3
if %M% LSS 1 (
    set /a Y-=1
    set /a M+=12
)
ren myFolder "%Y%-%M%"
```

However, depending on the date format you use it may look slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

ren *-04 *-01

Comment: That's correct (and I have given +1). Although I made a mistake in the question - sorry! I have now changed the source folder name in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The version of the answered question for UK date format (DD-MM-YYYY) is:

```
setlocal

@REM example:  11-06-2009
set stamp=%DATE%
@REM get the year

set year=%stamp:~6,4%
@REM example: 2009
@REM get the month

set month=%stamp:~3,2%
@REM example:  06

@REM subtract 3 months
set /a month=%month%-3
@REM example:  3

@REM test if negative (we rolled back beyond 1st January)
if %month% LSS 1  (
  set /a month=%month%+12
  @REM example: 8

  set /a year=%year%-1
  @REM example: 2008
)

@REM prepend with zero for single-digit month numbers
set month=0%month%

@REM take last 2 digits of THAT
set month=%month:~-2%

set newFolder=%year%-%month%

move c:\myfiles\myFolder\ %newFolder%

endlocal
```

Comment: @Sohnee - did you change something in the edit? It looks identical to me.